# Using RavenDb FilesStore from F# Interactive hangs

Tags: c#, f#, ravendb, ravenfs

I am trying to access a ravendb file system from an f# script.

I have this code:

```ml
#r "libs/Raven.Abstractions.dll"
#r "libs/Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll"

open Raven.Client.FileSystem

let fs = new FilesStore(Url = "http://localhost:8080", DefaultFileSystem = "TestFS")
let s = fs.Initialize() 

printfn "%A" s.Identifier
```

if I execute the script using `fsi` on the file or by compiling the script with `fsc` it runs and prints `http://localhost:8080` as expected but if I execute it in `F# interactive` inside VisualStudio it just hangs on the `fs.Initialize()` line

Now, if I call the `Initialize` method with `false` (ensureFileSystemExists) it runs ok in interactive.

Why does it work like this?

this is a piece of the [FilesStore.cs code](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/a3497c9f044f45b5e295f7fb9d7494df3c209a31/Raven.Client.Lightweight/FileSystem/FilesStore.cs):

```cs
if (ensureFileSystemExists && string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultFileSystem) == false)
{
    try
    {
        AsyncFilesCommands.ForFileSystem(DefaultFileSystem)
                                      .EnsureFileSystemExistsAsync()
                                      .Wait();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        if (failIfCannotCreate)
            throw;
    }
}
```

the `ensureFileSystemExists` variable is the `false` I pass on the second call to `Initialize` (the one that works on VS' F# interactive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the latest build, it should resolve this issue.
The underlying issue is the TPL scheduler used by default.